# Is there a way to use Cypher in python without setting up a Neo4j server?

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher

I would like to make queries on property graphs using the cypher language directly in python. For what I understand I first have to setup a Neo4j server and connect to it with Python.

But is there a way to directly make cypher requests in python graph objects, for example on Networkx objects? Or is there a python library that can set up the Neo4j server automatically?

Answer (score 0):

There is pypher library that can do it:
https://github.com/emehrkay/Pypher

Comment: I think it just allows to write cypher requests with Python, but I did not see any documentation on how to apply these requests to graphs in python without using neo4j ?